# removing white space in geom_tile and matching geom_vline&hline locations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have trouble with removing the white space between the rectangles when using `geom_tile` function.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(seq(2,16,2),seq(17,39,2)),
  y = c(rep(c(seq(8,26,2),seq(27,45,2)),each=20)),
  z = c(1:400))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(z)), colour = "grey50")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=6),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=24),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

until here I understand why this is happens. To move forward I can convert `x and y` to factor levels to remove the space! But this time I lost the `geom_vline` and `geom_hline` lines. This is probably happened converted `x and y` factor levels.

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(x), factor(y))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(z)), colour = "grey50")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=6),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=24),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  #scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

and when I add factor levels to `geom_vline&geom_hline` getting this error!

> Error in UseMethod("rescale") :    no applicable method for 'rescale'
>   applied to an object of class "factor"

```
  ggplot(df, aes(factor(x), factor(y))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(z)), colour = "grey50")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=factor(6)),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+         geom_hline(aes(yintercept=factor(24)),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  #scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. The first one is to adjust `width` and `height` of the tiles:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(z)), colour = "grey50", width = 2, height = 2)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=6),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=24),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=seq(0,50,1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

The second one is to change the values of `xintercept` and `yintercept`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(x), factor(y))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(z)), colour = "grey50")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=9),linetype="dashed",colour="red",size=1)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

which come from

```
match(6, unique(df$x))
# [1] 3
match(24, unique(df$y))
# [1] 9
```

That is, now we need to specify the number of a factor level of interest. In this case both 6 and 24 were used as factor levels, so we could do this, but in general this approach may not work as you may want a line at a nonexistent factor level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I liked the first solution better! Thanks a lot! As you pointed out it would be difficult to find every factor level of interest for every point if you have large set of the data!